# Dentro de setInterval, o "this" não aponta para a função que o chamou

Tags: javascript, scope, setinterval

O contexto no qual essa arrow foi criada foi diretamente no método `setInterval`, porém o `this` aponta para a `idade` dentro do objeto `Pessoa`, por quê? O `this` no arrow é baseado no contexto em que foi escrito, no caso o contexto de uma função chamada `setInterval`, certo?

```js
function Pessoa(){
    this.idade = 0

    setInterval(() => {
        this.idade++
        console.log(this.idade)
    },1000)
}

new Pessoa();
```

O segundo caso é o porquê de ter que usar `bind` no mesmo código sem arrow? Como é uma função, por que não aponta para o objeto que está criando ela?

```js
console.log(this === window);

function Pessoa(){
    this.idade = 0;

    setInterval(function(){
        this.idade++
        console.log(this.idade)
    }.bind(this),1000);
}

new Pessoa();
```

Answer (score 1):

Isso está explicado na [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval#The_this_problem):

> *Code executed by `setInterval()` runs in a separate execution context than the function from which it was called. As a consequence, the `this` keyword for the called function is set to the `window` (or global) object, it is not the same as the `this` value for the function that called `setTimeout`.*

Em tradução livre:

> O código executado por `setInterval` roda em um contexto separado da função onde ele foi chamado. Consequentemente, o `this` da função chamada é setado para o objeto `window` (ou global), e não é o mesmo `this` da função que chamou `setTimeout`.

Podemos ver esse comportamento alterando um pouco o seu exemplo:

```js
var x = 0, id = 0;
function Pessoa(){
    this.idade = 0;

    id = setInterval(function() {
        this.idade++;
        console.log(this == window, this.idade); // true NaN
        // só pra não ficar executando eternamente
        if (x++ >= 2) clearInterval(id);
    }, 1000);
}

new Pessoa();
```

Rodando em um *browser*, o `this` será igual a `window`, conforme dito na documentação. E como `window.idade` não foi definido (pois na linha `this.idade = 0`, o `this` refere-se à `Pessoa`), então dentro da função o valor de `this.idade` é `undefined`, já que ele está tentando pegar `window.idade`.

---

Já usando *arrow function*, o `this` não é alterado desta maneira, e refere-se à própria `Pessoa`:

```js
var x = 0, id = 0;
function Pessoa(){
    this.idade = 0;

    id = setInterval(() => {
        this.idade++;
        console.log(this == window, this, this.idade); // false { "idade": valor } valor da idade 
        // só pra não ficar executando eternamente
        if (x++ >= 2) clearInterval(id);
    }, 1000);
}

new Pessoa();
```

---

E usando [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) também funciona, pois o retorno de `bind` é uma função igual à original, mas com o `this` setado para o valor indicado:

```js
var x = 0, id = 0;
function Pessoa(){
    this.idade = 0;

    id = setInterval(function() {
        this.idade++;
        console.log(this == window, this, this.idade); // false { "idade": valor } valor da idade 
        // só pra não ficar executando eternamente
        if (x++ >= 2) clearInterval(id);
    }.bind(this), 1000);
}

new Pessoa();
```

No caso, `.bind(this)` está fora da função anônima, então naquele ponto o `this` refere-se a `Pessoa`. Ou seja, o `bind` retornou uma função igual à função anônima, mas com o `this` setado para a `Pessoa`.

---

O que confunde nos casos acima é que a cada momento o `this` pode representar uma coisa diferente. É confuso mesmo:

[image]